# The "Scope" of ELL

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, scope

Now, let's see, [my last question,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170111/mcat-and-m-d-please-explain-more)  was **closed** as **off-topic.**
(Although the word is translated in my native language, in the image below, I did not want to look at it because I wanted to understand what it meant in *English*.)

It came from a TOEFL textbook.

[image]

On the other hand,  [this earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169897/confusion-about-the-u-s-after-secondary-level-educational-systems-words) of mine was seen as completely acceptable.

Have you ever taken a TOEFL test as a native speaker?

I took it on 23th June. It was, **HILARIOUSLY** more difficult than 5 years ago.

For example, as far as I remember a question similar to below was in the listening section.

> Mercury has weak magnetic field so on and so forth and its core is not exactly made of iron but a bit rotten iron, magnetic field should not be captured on the planets nearer to the Sun than the Earth but a space shuttle called *** detected interestingly because *blah, blah*...

Such questions comes from your country's test center, [ETS,](https://www.ets.org/) in your country. And the score will be the measurement of entering into your country's college or either the measurement of **OUR** country's English level ( which in my opinion crazy. )

So, what is the scope on ELL  when we consider asking a question? Will someone define it, please?

Comment: Without seeing what the question reads, we can't tell you if it's on topic or not. I'm not really sure how the content of your question here, talking about Mercury, have anything to do with the question you've linked to.

Comment: That's the point what I would like to ask you. Even though, if it does not look a bit "not English learning", should I said at the title or somewhere, it comes from a TOEFL textbook, does it fulfill the **criteria** of here??

Comment: This meta question seems like it might be asking for a general summary of all our guidelines and principles of topicality/scope. But that's far too broad: there are dozens of meta questions about *particular aspects* of the site's scope, and if someone did try to explain everything, it would be far too easy to take some minor omission or inconsistency in their answer as evidence of big problems with the site that don't really exist or aren't actually worth worrying about.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be asking about why a particular question was closed and how context can change things. (Since we have a close reason specifically for questions that are unclear because they need more details, a partial answer to that would be that context is indeed quite important and can make the difference between closed and open.) But it's not clear what you're really asking here, so please [edit] so we can tell.

Comment: Discussion *on meta* is okay.  The whole point of meta is to get discussion off the main site, so we can focus on the English language over there.  But it's not clear what *this* discussion is about.  Your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with TOEFL, it doesn't appear to have anything to do with Mercury, and it doesn't appear to be a question about the English language.  Can you double-check and make sure you linked to the right question?

Comment: Yes, because the test itself TOEFL covers so broad. What can I do about it?

Comment: This site is for questions about the English Language... that's it. If the question isn't about English, it's not going to be on topic here. As far as I'm aware, there isn't a test prep Stack Exchange site or one for college prep/applications. There are, however, thousands of such sites on the internet. So, ask questions here about English and find somewhere else to ask questions about your application process.

Comment: Could you confirm what your actual question is? The title isn't one, and after that only "Have you ever took TOEFL test as a native speaker?" (which I think will only garner opinions even if you specify where your concern is) and "So what is the scope of here when we ELL consider to ask a question??? Will someone define please?" (which is far to vague, other than pointing you  to the Help Center which defines basically what should/should not be asked).

Comment: The cold hard truth? Your English is not *yet* up to par, you would not get a 7 in IELTS, and neither a B2 i.e. Cambridge First certificate, and these two exams are easier than TOEFL, which I think is a horrible horrible exam, bordering on the inhumane.

Comment: Yeah, I know...but TOEIC sucks. Actually at this age, I am having a trouble with my company's income and I MUST get through whatever it takes in order to prove at least I am at 90. The exam was crazy. The security check was like entering North Korea...

Comment: You have to clarify the last sentence in your question. Are you asking what questions are on topic? Are you asking why your last question was closed but not an older one? Are you asking what is the PURPOSE of ELL, if it's not to help learners understand the "exam system" (I'm guessing here) that is used in Anglophone speaking countries. I have edited the post, and interpreted what I think you meant by *brain chain* ***…the "chain" of English brain…** but I accept I might be completely wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your kind treatment. Although...it is closed and I completely accept it...

Comment: Well take a look at the corrections and if there any you do not agree with or understand, you can ask on the main site and link it back to here :)

Comment: Thank a lot. I appreciate it. But closed was closed........so thank you ^^:)

Comment: @KentaroTomono When a question is put on hold, it is often intended that the question be edited to address the problem so that we can reopen it. Your question was put on hold as unclear. If you edit it to clarify it during the on-hold stage it automatically goes into a queue to be reviewed to see if it can be reopened. The question only moves to "closed" from on-hold if it isn't edited. Even "closed" is not intended to be a permanent state if the question can be improved to address the concern. More information from the [help]: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 4):

I think we have a failure to communicate here.  You wrote:

> Could anyone explain **why** MCAT is required to take for students.

This doesn't look like a question about English.  But I now believe that you *do* have a question about the English language.  It seems that you want to know specifically what the MCAT is, when it's taken and for what purpose.  That's why your original question says:

> Is this test simply the entry test in order to be a doctor after you become M.D? (Doctor Of Medicine) prepared for **undergraduate** students?

Your first sentence makes it sound like you want to know the rationale of the admissions officers, how they chose the MCAT and why they made it a requirement.  But I don't think that's the case; I think you meant to ask a *what* question, not a *why* question.

Unfortunately, the question in its current state is not very clear.  I think the first sentence communicated the wrong thing, and the questions at the end are very hard to understand as well.  But I think if you [edit your question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/170111/edit) to make it a little bit clearer what you're asking, we can probably get it reopened, and then someone can help you out by writing an answer for it.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. I was actually, at that time, tired of asking ( I of course appreciate your supports ) about jargons. And I may have got upset even though I am not a huge downvoter ( it is even on the contrary ) I simultaneously banned for days **right after asking this question in the matter**. Well..but let me tell you, it is **you country** which gives this test whatever you would like it or not.

Comment: I understand your frustration.  Just to make sure you understand, the three-day suspension was for an unrelated matter, which was explained in the message you received along with the suspension.  You were not suspended because of this question, and you will not be suspended for posting a discussion on meta.

Comment: @KentaroTomono I am not quite sure I understand which test you have been asking about and where your frustration comes from. You seem to be asking about the TOEFL, but you also express your frustration with the MCAT. FYI, they are two completely different standardized examinations, serving distinct purposes. The TOEFL is administered by [ETS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Educational_Testing_Service), arguably an international organization while the MCAT is run by the [AAMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_of_American_Medical_Colleges). If you want to know what they are, Google.